# Data binding on actionSearch Edittex

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

How to bind data on clicking the `actionSearch` button of soft keyboard with `@BindingAdapter` in kotlin?

My editText:

```py
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

My viewModel:

```py
class RelationListViewModel: BaseViewModel(){
   //..    
    val text: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `BindingAdapter` for `setOnEditorActionListener`

```
class ViewModel {
    private val editorActionListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener

    init {
        this.editorActionListener = TextView.OnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                // do your search logic
                true
            } else false
        }
    }

    companion object {

        @BindingAdapter("onEditorActionListener")
        fun bindOnEditorActionListener(editText: EditText, editorActionListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener) {
            editText.setOnEditorActionListener(editorActionListener)
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in your xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        app:onEditorActionListener="@{viewModel.editorActionListener}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data Binding for onEditoractionListener**  can be achieved  as

```
fun onEditorAction(view: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //todo action you want on this
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

And in the layout file use as

```
 android:onEditorAction="@{(view,actionId,event) -> viewmodel.onEditorAction(view,actionId,event)}"
```